# Configure "service" in Gitlab pipeline using commandline arguments

Tags: docker, networking, service, gitlab

I need to use `.gitlab-ci.yml`'s `services` section ([Services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/)) to run a rather untypical server providing service over network to the job's main image. The network communication has to run both ways, i.e. both the client (in regular pipeline job) will initiate connection to the (service) server and the other way around.

The GL's service server configuration is rather simple, but still some files have to be configured for it.

Doing the configuration using `command` or `entrypoint` doesn't seem to be feasible as they seem to be designed rather for a single command:

[Available settings for services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#available-settings-for-services)

I don't quite envision putting entire script in a very long JSON list.

The obvious problem is that `service` doesn't seem to have `script:` section like the normal pipeline job does (why? seems a rather weird omission to me).

The only option available to me seems to be building a service's docker image with the network server preinstalled and preconfigured.

It's kind of overkill though for a simple service. Seems I have hit weird middle ground between using prebuilt service image like `mysql` and potentially elaborate process of building Docker image and putting it in my org's Container Registry (for which I don't even have admin rights plus we're using hosted Gitlab service which might introduce more complications perhaps).

I'm a *total* Gitlab CI/CD newbie. Please help, preferably with configuration examples.